# Struggling to create an appropriate print method for my object

Tags: java, arrays, oop, printing

So I have an array of objects stored in a class lableled Warhouse. After the user enters a String I want it to be passed into a method placed in a class that does not contain the array of objects where it is matched against through a reference of the array of objects from the Warehouse class, then print out the details line by line:

```
public void printItemDetail(String itemNo)
{
    Item [] items = inventory.getItems();
    for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        if(itemNo.equals(items[i].getItemNo()))
        {
            System.out.println(itemNo);
            System.out.println(items[i].getItemName());
        }
    }
```

This method is located in my object class. I'm assuming that I can just get rid of the get methods, and the array of the objects since it is already contained within the class itself?

Comment: so what is your question ? what make you to post question ?

Comment: In my main, case 1. Say the user enters the string "A11111" which is an item within my warehouse class. How would I develop a method that prints out that item with all the rest of its characteristics? I'm trying to implement it in my item class

Comment: You need to try writing that code, first.  Then we can help you.  95% of the code given is unrelated to your problem. Learn how to create a [mcve], and you will get higher quality answers ... or possibly answer your question yourself before posting it.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: @Mcbever What inventory refer to ?

Comment: My Items class, Ive added it in

Comment: so where the `printItemDetail` get called ?  In which class ?

Answer (score 0):

U need to make a call to loadData to assign values to objects ;  Then in validateItemNo compare itemNo == (ur object).itemNo .... if 'true', call getters using object. Hope this gives u some idea !

Comment: So I would call loadData in my main?

Comment: Yes .. also why unnecessary cases ?

Comment: Ohhhhh okay now I am understanding. So in my printItemDetail method, I have to match the string itemNo through my array of objects, but I am not sure how to do that as they are stored in my Warehouse class

Comment: saw the edits...i remember u had many getters . u need to call each of the getter belonging to the object when matched..

Comment: Yes, but they exist in the Item class where my printItemDetail method is located. I tried to access the array of objects in the warehouse class using a getter, then storing them into a seperate array in that method, then work on it from there.

Answer (score 0):

There are something wrong in your code.

1. You should place  `sc.nextLine()` before  `System.out.println("Please Enter the Item Number");`
2. To compare the equality between two String, use `equals()` instead of `==`

   ```
    if (itemNo != "A11111" && itemNo != "B22222" && itemNo != 
      "C33333" && itemNo != "D44444" && itemNo != "E55555") {
           .......
   }
   ```

   The code above totally wrong. You should write in this way

   ```
   if (!itemNo.equals("A11111") && (!itemNo.equals("B22222")) && (!itemNo.equals("C33333")) && (!itemNo.equals("D44444")) && (!itemNo.equals("E55555"))) {
            ......  
    }
   ```

> Say the user enters "A11111" I want it to print out all the details of
>   the item whose item number is A11111

So if you want to compare user input (A11111) with the items array, write like this

```
 if(itemNo.equals("A11111"))
 {
     loadData();   //  assign values to objects
 }
```

Comment: Yeah I figured that out, I changed my validation method to the above, but I'm not sure why I would use the loadData method right after

Comment: in my printItemDetail method can't I just access the array of item objects in the warehouse class and act on them from there?

Comment: you can pass it by parameter